# Difficulty Creating column of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to create  a new column of a dataframe based on existing columns, however I want it to be conditional on another existing column in my dataframe.  The following code is not working.  Does anyone know why?

```
if CV['keyword'] == 0:
    CV['left out'] = (CV['Prediction Numerator'] - (CV['Rate'] *10000))/(CV['Prediction Denominator'] - 10000)
else:
    CV['left out'] = (CV['Prediction Numerator'] - (CV['Rate'] *10000 * 10))/(CV['Prediction Denominator'] - (10000 * 10))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bwei\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 709, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here's a snippet of the first 4 columns of my dataframe.

```
        Zip  keyword  Prediction Numerator  Prediction Denominator  
0     01001        0        7650546.693200            40002.558782   
1     01001        0        7650546.693200            40002.558782   
2     01001        0        7650546.693200            40002.558782   
3     01001        0        7650546.693200            40002.558782   
4     01002        0            157.951741                0.718621   
5     01002        0            157.951741                0.718621   
6     01005        0        3600150.148240            20000.671431   
7     01005        0        3600150.148240            20000.671431   
8     01007        0        6932235.816260            30000.936191   
9     01007        0        6932235.816260            30000.936191   
10    01007        0        6932235.816260            30000.936191
```

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
CV.loc[CV['keyword']==0,'left out']=expression1
CV.loc[CV['keyword']!=0,'left out']=expression2
```

Comment: This was exactly what I want, thanks! Just so I understand what it's doing, it's essentially looking at locations where keyword = 0, and then setting left out equal to each given expression?

Comment: Exactly - might not be fastest as you filter 2x but simplest to read/understand

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `CV['keyword'] == 0`, you should use `'keyword' in CV.columns` to see if there is a column named "keyword" in CV.

Comment: No the keyword column is always there, I just want to say if keyword = 0 for a specific then perform operation a and if it's equal to 0, perform operation b.

Comment: You're going to have to describe more precisely what you want. What does it mean to compare an entire column to 0? There are many possible interpretations. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I edited my question to give more clarity.  For example, at row 0, keyword = 0, so for that I'd want ['left out'] to be equal to the if, if keyword == 1, I'd want ['left out'] to be equal to the else.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
if CV['keyword'] == 0:
```

then `CV['keyword']` is a column, and comparing it to 0 returns a boolean series. You cannot perform an `if` on such a series (which value would determine if it's `True` or `False`?), and hence the error.

Fortunately, `CV.columns` works pretty much like a Python list, so you can check membership using it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
CV['left out'] = np.where(CV['keyword'] == 0,
  (CV['Prediction Numerator'] - (CV['Rate'] *10000))/(CV['Prediction Denominator'] - 10000), 
   (CV['left out'] = (CV['Prediction Numerator'] - (CV['Rate'] * 10000 * 10))/(CV['Prediction Denominator'] - (10000 * ))
)
```

Comment: using the same if else control flow?

Comment: You have two formulas and you want to use the first formula for rows where ```CV['keyword'] == 0``` and the other formula for rows where that's not the case, is that correct? ```np.where``` does the if else element wise in  a vectorized way. You would have to loop through your rows using if you want to use if else which would be inefficient.